# How does `NSAttibutedString` equate attribute values of type `Any`?

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring, any, equatable

The `enumerateAttribute(_:in:options:using:)` method of `NSAttributedString` appears to equate arbitrary instances of type `Any`.  Of course, `Any` does not conform to `Equatable`, so that should not be possible.

#### Question:  How does the method compare one instance of `Any` to another?

*Context:  In Swift, I am subclassing NSTextStorage, and have need to provide my own implementation of this method **in Swift**.*

Observations:

- `NSAttributedString` attributes come in key-value pairs, with the keys being instances of type `NSAttributedString.Key` and the values being instances of type `Any?`, with each pair being associated with one or more ranges of characters in the string.  At least, that is how the data structure appears from the outside; the internal implementation is opaque.
- The `enumerateAttribute` method walks through the entire range of an `NSAttributedString`, effectively identifying each different value corresponding to a specified key, and with the ranges over which that value applies.
- The values corresponding to a given key could be of multiple different types.
- `NSAttributedString` seemingly has no way of knowing what underlying types the `Any` values might be, and thus seemingly no way of type casting in order to make a comparison of two given `Any` values.
- Yet, the method somehow is differentiating among ranges of the string based on differences in the `Any` values.
- Interestingly, the method is able to differentiate between values even when the underlying type **does not conform** to `Equatable`.  I take this to be a clue that the method may be using some sort of reflection to perform the comparison.
- Even more interesting, the method goes so far as to differentiate between values when the underlying type **does conform** to `Equatable` and the difference between two values is a difference that the specific implementation of `Equatable` intentionally ignores.  In other words, even if `a == b` returns true, if there is a difference in opaque properties of a and b that are ignored by `==`, the method will treat the values as being different, not the same.
- I assume the method bridges to an implementation in ObjC.

#### Is the answer:  *It cannot be done in Swift?*

Comment: There's nothing magic about it. Each keys expect value of a certain type (`NSAttributedString.Key.font` expects a `UIFont`, `.foregroundColor` expects a `UIColor`, etc.). You can find that by digging into the documentation so you just cast `Any` to the corresponding type.

Comment: What do you mean "it cannot be done in Swift"? What cannot be done? You can certainly call `enumerateAttribute` and it works fine, so what exactly is the problem here? "I am subclassing NSTextStorage, and have need to provide my own implementation of this method" Why would you need to override this method?

Answer (score 0):

As you know, Cocoa is Objective-C, so these are Objective-C NSDictionary objects, not Swift Dictionary objects. So equality comparison between them uses Objective-C `isEqual`, not Swift `==`. We are not bound by Swift strict typing, the Equatable protocol, or anything else from Swift.

To illustrate, here's a slow and stupid but effective implementation of style run detection:

```
let s = NSMutableAttributedString(
    string: "howdy", attributes: [.foregroundColor:UIColor.red])
s.addAttributes([.foregroundColor:UIColor.blue], 
    range: NSRange(location: 2, length: 1))
var lastatt = s.attributes(at: 0, effectiveRange: nil)
for ix in 1..<5 {
    let newatt = s.attributes(at:ix, effectiveRange:nil)
    if !(newatt as NSDictionary).isEqual(to: lastatt) {
        print("style run ended at \(ix)")
        lastatt = newatt
    }
}
```

That correctly prints:

```
style run ended at 2
style run ended at 3
```

So since it is always possible to compare the attributes at any index with the attributes at another, it is possible to implement attribute enumeration in Swift. (Whether that's a good idea is another question.)